# multiple random values Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

For the purpose of my script, I need to generate multiple random values Around 50, where my data feeder is an array.

I can manage to do it with code duplication but I prefer a smarter way using some loop.

My code (JSR223 PreProcessor) looks like:

```
import java.util.*;  

String[] categories = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

int idx1 = new Random().nextInt(categories.length);
String category1 = (categories[idx1]);

int idx2 = new Random().nextInt(categories.length);
String category2 = (categories[idx2]);

vars.put("pickValue1", category1);
vars.put("pickValue2", category2);
```

Then I use pickValue1, pickValue2 in the script.

How can I use smarter looping, without copy/paste   50 times the below code?

```
int idx1 = new Random().nextInt(categories.length);
String category1 = (categories[idx1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid code duplication:

```
String[] categories = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for (int i=0; i<categories.length; i++) {
   vars.put("pickValue" + (i+1), categories[new Random().nextInt(categories.length)]);
}
```

Comment: thanks @user7294900
Also I have 1 more value which I uses as: 
Integer.valueOf(category1[0])+206).toString(), so how can i increment the value by 206?
thanks

Comment: @vlatko606 you can start array with 206 instead of 0

Comment: have another scenario where I need 2 variables.
1. generated from the array (0-5
2. the same value, plus increased by 206 (206, 207, 208....)
I tried like, but its not working
vars.put("pickID" + (i+1), categories[new Random().nextInt(categories.length)] + (+206));
   vars.put("pickValue" + (i+1), categories[new Random().nextInt(categories.length)]);

Comment: @vlatko606 can you start a new question with new case?

Comment: @user7294900-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855073/multiple-random-values-into-multiple-variables-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest would be just using [__Random()  function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) just where you need to generate the random value

```
${__Random(0,6,)}
```

However if your requirement is more specific you can refactor your code to this one-liner:

```
1.upto(50, { index ->  vars.put('pickValue' + index, org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, 6) as String)})
```

More information:

- [Groovy For Loop Examples](http://grails.asia/groovy-for-loop-examples)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)