# multiple random values into Multiple variables - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Based on this thread [multiple random values Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852950/multiple-random-values-jmeter) ,
I managed to created 1 variable, based on the data from array.

Now I need to fetch two variables: pickID & pickValue, where pickValue remains the same, but pickID should be increased by 206.

So I will have random pairs like:

"id": "210", "value": "4"  or "id": "208", "value": "2"

If I try as:

```
import java.util.*;  


String[] categories = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for (int i=0; i<categories.length; i++) {
   vars.put("pickID" + (i+1), categories[new Random().nextInt(categories.length)] + (+206)  );
   vars.put("pickValue" + (i+1), categories[new Random().nextInt(categories.length)]);
}
```

I got value next to it, instead of increased.
ex:

```
    "id": "4206",
    "value": "1"
},
{
    "id": "1206",
    "value": "2"
```

How to increase pickID by 206?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding 2 strings and you should be adding 2 integers and convert the result into a string.

Something like:

```
int[] categories = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    vars.put("pickID" + (i + 1), String.valueOf(categories[new Random().nextInt(categories.length)] + 206));
    vars.put("pickValue" + (i + 1), String.valueOf(categories[new Random().nextInt(categories.length)]));
}
```

More information:

- [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))
- [String.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int))
- [How to Perform Arithmetic Operations on Numeric Variables When Load Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-arithmetic-operations-on-numeric-variables-when-load-testing)